# Using Regex in Notepad++, how do I select only the period inside some specific lines but not inside others

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Regex in Notepad++, how do I select only the period inside these lines:

```
<div class="english">One. Two. Three. Four. Five.</div>
```

but leaving alone the period inside these ones:

```
<div class="spanish">Uno. Dos. Tres. Cuatro. Cinco.</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select only the dots between `<div class="english">` and `</div>` you can use:

```
(?:<div class="english">|(?!^)\G)(?:[^.<]|<(?!/div>))*\K\.
```

Explanation and [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/21):

```
(?:                     # non-capturing group
  <div class="english"> # our delimiter
|                       # or
  (?!^)\G               # the end of the last match
)
(?:
  [^.<]               # any character except '.' or '<' (even newline)...
|                     # or ...
  <(?!/div>)          # '<' not followed by a '/div>'
)*
\K                    # leave what we found so far out of the match
\.                    # match the dot
```

See reference for the use of [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) and [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

Comment: Fantastic @Robin, much appreciated, specially the explanations. 
This is also the solution for a myriad of other replacements I have to do. Absolutely priceless. Thank you very much.

Comment: @rafael.minuesa I refactored the regex to remove the redundant parts, if that solved your issue you can mark the answer as accepted. Happy to be of help !

Comment: Done @Robin, the redundant parts were also appreciated nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="(?!english)[^"]*">.*?<\/div>\K|\.(?=.*?<\/div>)
```

You can do this using `\K`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/18